# SQLite query join logic

Tags: sql

I am able to compute it in excel but finding it challenging to come up with the right logic in SQLite.

So far I have tried this:

```
   SELECT ProductName, productID, OrderDate
     FROM Product
LEFT JOIN OrderDetails 
       ON Product.ProductId = OrderDetails.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Orders 
       ON Orders.OrderId = OrderDetails.OrderId
    WHERE OrderDate 
  BETWEEN '1996/10/01' AND '1997/01/01' and 
          ProductID IS NULL
 GROUP BY ProductName
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean, "not having outer join in SQLite"? There are three outer joins--left, right & full. When you say, "outer join", do you mean full outer join? Please edit to clarify. Expressing full outer join is an easily found faq. But you don't need full outer join for "find products that have not been ordered in the past three months from the Fiscal year-end". And "find rows that have no match in another table" is another easily googled faq.

Comment: Sorry, wrote that wrong!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you could simply use a `NOT EXISTS` condition to filter customers that have no `Orders` for the given date interval, like :

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Orders o
    WHERE 
        o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
        AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996/10/01' AND '1997/01/01'
)
```

This could also be done using a `LEFT JOIN` combined with a `IS NULL` condition :

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o
    ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 
    AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996/10/01' AND '1997/01/01'
WHERE o.OrderID IS NULL
```

In the W3School fiddle, both queries return 57 records.

Comment: Thank You, I'll try and update you. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

A variation of your query can be used to get all the distinct products that **were ordered in the past 3 months**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Products.ProductID
FROM Products
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductId = OrderDetails.ProductId
INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.OrderId = OrderDetails.OrderId
WHERE Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996/10/01' AND '1997/01/01'
```

Now you can use the above query to get all the products that were **not** ordered in the past 3 months:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Products.ProductID 
    FROM Products
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductId = OrderDetails.ProductId
    INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.OrderId = OrderDetails.OrderId
    WHERE Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996/10/01' AND '1997/01/01'
) t 
ON t.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE t.ProductID IS NULL
```

or:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName
FROM Products 
WHERE ProductID NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT Products.ProductID
    FROM Products
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductId = OrderDetails.ProductId
    INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.OrderId = OrderDetails.OrderId
    WHERE Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996/10/01' AND '1997/01/01'
)
```

Both queries return 19 products:

```
ProductID   ProductName
4           Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning
5           Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix
6           Grandma's Boysenberry Spread
7           Uncle Bob's Organic Dried Pears
8           Northwoods Cranberry Sauce
10          Ikura
15          Genen Shouyu
18          Carnarvon Tigers
20          Sir Rodney's Marmalade
24          Guaraná Fantástica
25          NuNuCa Nuß-Nougat-Creme
32          Mascarpone Fabioli
39          Chartreuse verte
43          Ipoh Coffee
45          Røgede sild
51          Manjimup Dried Apples
52          Filo Mix
58          Escargots de Bourgogne
67          Laughing Lumberjack Lager
```

You could also get the same results with `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName 
FROM Products p INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ProductID
    FROM Products 
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT DISTINCT Products.ProductID
    FROM Products
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Products.ProductId = OrderDetails.ProductId
    INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.OrderId = OrderDetails.OrderId
    WHERE Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996/10/01' AND '1997/01/01'
) t ON t.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Comment: Thank You, I would try and update you guys. I appreciate the feedback